# Clang: Trouble using bind or mem_fn with string::c_str and transform

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, libc++, stdbind

Trying to convert a vector of std::string to a vector of const char*:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    values.push_back("test1");
    values.push_back("test2");
    values.push_back("test3");

    std::vector<const char*> c_values(values.size());

    std::transform(values.begin(), values.end(), c_values.begin(), std::mem_fn(&std::string::c_str));
    std::transform(values.begin(), values.end(), c_values.begin(), std::bind(&std::string::c_str, std::placeholders::_1));
    std::transform(values.begin(), values.end(), c_values.begin(), [](const std::string& str) { return str.c_str(); });

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with g++ (4.7.2), all three options compile and link fine. When compiling with clang, options 1 and 2 fail to link, producing:

```
$ clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ stringtransform.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str() const", referenced from:
    _main in stringtransform-ff30c1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I am finding I need to use the lambda version (option 3) if I want it to link correctly across platforms using both g++ and clang. Am I running into a linker bug or a hole in clang's C++11 support, or is there something wrong with how I'm invoking the mem_fn() and bind() versions?

EDIT:

Error still present on latest Xcode (6.3.2, with clang version 6.1.0:

```
$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me your examples don't even compile with `clang` (much less link), as `std::bind` hasn't been implemented in my `XCode/*/include/c++` directory. What version of clang are you using?

Comment: I don't have an answer unfortunately, but here is a simpler example that reproduces what you talk about, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985aa0da6589e155a27f . It is also fix by using -Os

Comment: @user14717 note the `-stdlib=libc++` option, which uses the libc++ standard library instead of the ancient version of libstdc++ from 2007 that comes with OS X. It should compile if you use libc++ or install a modern version of libstdc++ (e.g. via homebrew) and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in libc++ versions since LLVM 3.6.0

My guess is they didn't export the `std::string::c_str()` symbol from their DSO, so the symbol is not global and can't be linked to.

The `&string::c_str` pointer to member function creates a dependency on the symbol for that function, which can't be resolved by the linker because the definition of the symbol is not global. It sometimes works when optimising because the `c_str()` function gets inlined, and no external definition for the symbol is needed.

You can workaround it by instantiating the function yourself in your code:

```
#ifdef _LIBCPP_VERSION
template const char* std::string::c_str() const;
#endif
```

**However** you should be aware that your code has a problem. Options 1 and 2  aren't guaranteed to work with any standard library implementation:

```
std::mem_fn(&std::string::c_str)
std::bind(&std::string::c_str, std::placeholders::_1)
```

For non-virtual member functions like `std::basic_string::c_str()` the standard library is free to define additional overloads, or to use different signatures from those specified in the standard. This means any attempt to do `&std::a_class::a_nonvirtual_member_function` is non-portable, and potentially a bug.

For example, lots of C++98 code that did `&std::vector<X>::push_back` stopped compiling in C++11 because that is now an overloaded function (there's an overload taking a const lvalue reference and an overload taking an rvalue reference).

This specific example will probably work in practice, because no implementations overload `std::basic_string::c_str` or give it a funny signature.

The lambda function is fine, because that doesn't take the address of a member function, it just calls it:

```
[](const std::string& str) { return str.c_str(); }
```

This way the compiler finds the function using overload resolution, not via a dubious pointer to member function.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround: Compiling your code with -Os makes the issue go away.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a libc++ problem.

Given this,

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  string s("Hello, World!");
  const char * (std::string::*mem_c_str) () const = &std::string::c_str;
  cout << (s.*mem_c_str)() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

We get the same error.

It is fixed by using `-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++`. It seems to work for any `-On` flag.